# Is it possible to show labels in QGIS CLOUD?

Tags: qgis, labeling, cloud-gis, qgis-cloud

I have recently purchased the QGIS Cloud PRO version, but when I upload a map, I cannot visualize the labels of each layer.

Obviously, I have the labels activated on QGIS, but they just don't appear when uploading them to QGIS Cloud. 
Is there any option in QGIS Cloud I am missing about labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of QGIS are you using?

I used QGIS Free Plan to test but I noticed QGIS 3 does not support labeling whereas the older version of 2.18 support labeling exactly as set in the QGIS project. I suggest you try an order version.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was using the QGIS 3 version and seems like QGIS Cloud doesn't support the QGIS 3 labelling. Thank you very much, it was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Labels are available with QGIS3 now.

Comment: I will suggest adding some kind of directions and/or links to QGIS docs, if not this answer could be deleted.